# How to display only certain features in a layer in Global Mapper?

Tags: definition-query, global-mapper

Is there a way to restrict the records displayed on the screen from a shapefile or other layer type in Global Mapper?

In ArcGIS this is called a definition query. For example if I have a text attribute called type I want a query that says: "TYPE" = 'SIDE TRACK'

If I double click the layer in the *Overlay Control Center*, choose *Line Styles* and *Apply Styling Based on Attribute/Name Values*, I can then apply a Null style. This method works, but there are lots of different attribute combinations this would be quite tedious. I'm looking for a way to apply a SQL type query.

[image: This is an example of the current workaround]

Comment: I guess there's not a lot of Global Mapper users on GIS SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Search feature, so you can search all the vector features depending on their attributes. Then you can select all the features returned by the search (there is a button for  that) and then edit all selected  features (there is a button for that too). In the editing window you can move all the selected features to a new layer, then you can easily toggle their visibility independently of the rest of the loaded features.

Here you have an example screenshot of the search window selecting all point features with elevations greater than 2000 m
[image: search screenshot]